# Does Magento 1.9 use redis cache for showing data in getCart?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, redis, cart-items, cm-redissession

So,  I am using Magento 1.9 in our project. I have enabled Redis in magento and it is workingbperfectly fine.

I wanted to know if Magento 1.9 uses Redis cache for showing the data in cart?

If yes then how does it store the data in the Redis cache and read from it?